# Standard deviation with Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, math, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I am computing the SD of a vector using Apache Commons Math.  The problem:  I get different values than by hand

```
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();
stats.addValue(value1);
...
stats.addValue(value8);
stats.getStandardDeviation();
```

E.g., take the values [1699.0, 1819.0, 1699.0, 1719.0, 1689.0, 1709.0, 1819.0, 1689.0].  SD should be 52.067 but Commons Math = 55.662.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Apache *StandardDeviation* class can be used for computing both values: "Standard Deviation" and "Population Standard deviation".

For computing the second value initialize it with

```
    StandardDeviation sd = new StandardDeviation(false);
```

Example:

```
    double[] v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    StandardDeviation sd = new StandardDeviation(false);
    sd.evaluate(v);
    // returns 1.414

    StandardDeviation sd2 = new StandardDeviation();
    sd2.evaluate(v);
    // returns 1.581
```

Answer (score 6):

Apache is giving you the "Standard Deviation" but you are looking for the "Population Standard Deviation"

Maybe you could use `getPopulationVariance()` and then take the square root yourself?  I don't see a function for this in the DS library.