# How to customize excel formula in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

While writing excel code in java, I am currently looking for Standard Deviation Population formula in Apache Poi v4.1.1, which is not implemented hence exception is throwing, then appeared to have 2 solutions in my hand, #1) Implement custom formula #2) Tweak / Override existing formula

I am not sure how to override existing formula hence moved to solution 1, 
while doing this, I have some or the other issues

Problem: 
 Let us say, in my excel, column B has 250 rows (dynamic no. of rows, in some cases 240 rows) and according to std dev formula, I need to first find the mean, so my query here is

**Q #1**) how to  know or select the non-empty values (column or rows) to write my own custom code.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that, instead of implementing Standard deviation population formula, in Apache POI, there is a separate class available for Standard Deviation, we need to use it.

This link also useful [Standard deviation with Apache Commons Math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306207/standard-deviation-with-apache-commons-math)

Answer (score 0):

The formula can be added as a string.

So it must not be implemented in Apache Poi, but must be implemented in the excel running your xlsx file.

You can simply add it as follow:

```
String strFormula= ...; // For example for a sum can be the string SUM(A1:A10)
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula(strFormula);
```

Comment: I did and code failed with an exception, NotImplemented, then I realized formula I have used was not in poi api, hence want to write custom class to my formula